# Create a perfect square div responsive

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to create a perfect square div whose sides are equal to the smallest side of document.body? Either the width or height of the document. And it must to be responsive.

Comment: If I'm asking, is because I don't know. I would appreciate an answer and not a "-1"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How more explicit should I be?? The points that I've achieved don't allow me to upload a picture to explain the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found my solution. Sorry, I just realized in my previous comment, it wasn't working for me because the body has a default margin.

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body style="padding: 0;    margin: 0;">
  <div style="width: 100vmin; height: 100vmin; background-color: #333; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.outer {
 width:100%;
 height:0;
 padding-top:100%;
 position:relative;
 background:#eee;
}

.inner {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's taking the bigger side, else I would use 100vmin on both sides.